# How to validate an decrypted file with javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, encryption

I'm looking for a way to sync a encrypted file between users of a webapp which is javascript based.
That in itself would not be the problem. But as the file will be send encrypted to the server, the server can not check the content if it's valid.
The server might be several things, shared hosting(php?), dropbox, Google drive.
So I don't want to depend that. Both technically or security wise.
The javascript can always be tweaked locally to insert something which isn't wanted.

I'm thinking the decrypted file should be an xml which would make it easier to check the structure. And Xpath will allow easy search possibilities.
But some other format is also acceptable if the validation of the file is easier.

But what is the best way (if any) to validate the file when a second person gets it. And to prevent malicious code from being executed.
I know it might not be possible to do this foolproof.

*PS I'm not sure if this is the right stack exchange sub?*

Comment: What server side code do you use?

Comment: What's the purpose of sending the file encrypted?

Comment: @DieVeenman, updated my question to clarify this. If you know a good way to do this with PHP then it might be an option to scale it back.

Comment: I think `JSON` would be a much safer approach than XML. But it really depends on what you are sending out. If you are asking for a format for message exchange then `JSON` is ok.

Comment: @MinusFour can you give a reason why you would think *json* is more secure? I would think *xml* would be easier to check against an [xsd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29). Keep in mind the xml or json would be encrypted then decrypted.

Comment: Not sure I understand your primary concern. Do you want to prevent tampering of the ciphertext on transmission or do you want to run a virus scan on the received data? The XML schema validator that you want to use could have a bug and enable a malicious plaintext to run an exploit on the receiver.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I maily want to prevent malicous plaintext being inserted before encryption and sending it to the server. Because I think that will be nearly impossible I want to validate the given & decrypted data.

Comment: @janw, because the JSON spec is waaay more simpler than XML and it's only pair of keys and values. There are some gray areas of XML that allow things like [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Processing).

Comment: @ArtjomB. After viewing your profile I think you have the knowledge to help me. Would you be open to have a chat?